# Bulged/bent square with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, three.js

Been breaking my head about how to describe this, so let me just jump straight to the intended effect:

[image]

so I am **not** talking about the sides or the content, but just the way the square is 'bent' forward. So far I have been able to figure out no way to do this in CSS, but when going down the `Three.js` route there is `THREE.BendModifier`. Still even that one I haven't been able to get to generate the above (very simple) shape... and beyond that I can't seem to figure out a way to draw an HTML element in to a `WebGLRenderer` in the first place.

Note that I am not looking for a ready made solution (though I might reward one with a bounty), all I need is just a generic approach that would result in the above result. Considering all things that are possible in webbrowsers there must be a way...

Comment: probably have to use webgl to transform a div on the surface of a sphere somehow

Comment: @foreyez: Yeah, that's what I have been trying to do with `three.js`, but after messing with that for quite a while ('screenshotting' HTML is hard) I can't believe it can be this hard to get such a simple effect~

Comment: html2canvas is pretty simple to use, and then just use that as a texture in webgl.. but it depends if you want to have this interactive

Comment: @foreyez: Check the test console of `html2canvas` with a site that uses a lot of CSS3 and be sad :P . Oh well, if anybody can just tell me how to get that bulge/bent effect using for example a `BendModifier` I will already be a happy man :P .

Comment: check this out.. someone made a cylinder in css. that's almost a sphere http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/qsdAH

Comment: @foreyez Oh wow, if I would only have text that would theoretically speaking be an option indeed :O Though I would then have to place every single character in it's own rotated `<div>`...